# Verify/validate an AWS Cognito access token from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm building a mobile app with React Native. With the help of this library, https://github.com/AirLabsTeam/react-native-aws-cognito-js, I'm able to sign-up and sign-in an user through the app and Cognito returns an access token to the app.

Now, the app will make api calls to a Rails backend with this token. (for every api call.)

1) How can the Rails side verify if the token is good or not?

2) How can I get the user email?

3) Is there an api endpoint from AWS?

4) Is there an example out there similar to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

No need to convert to pem, the ruby gem 'jwt' does the trick:

```
aws_idp = Faraday.get('https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json').body
jwt_config = JSON.parse(aws_idp, symbolize_names: true)
JWT.decode(token, nil, true, {jwks: jwt_config, algorithms: ['RS256'] })
```

The token sent to the server is the id token which you can get from amplify JS lib:

```
cognitoUser.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
```

If decode passes without an exception the token is verified
Make sure to check if the algorithm in the idp is indeed RS256

Answer (score 2):

I might have found out a way to do this.

1) Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

2) Add these 3 env variables:

```
export AWS_REGION=us-west-2   
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="Your AWS Access Key ID"   
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= "Your AWS Secret Access Key"
```

3) Create a new file. I put the following in app/modules/Aws.rb

```
require 'aws-sdk'

cognitoidentityprovider = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])

begin
  cognito_user = cognitoidentityprovider.get_user({
    access_token: "Token coming from the APP"
  })

  email_verified = cognito_user.user_attributes
                               .detect{ |attribute_type| attribute_type["name"] === "email_verified" && attribute_type["value"] === "true" }

  if email_verified.nil?
    raise "Email is not verified"
  else
    puts "EMAIL IS GOOD!" 
    puts cognito_user.username
  end

rescue StandardError => msg
  puts "ERROR!"
  puts msg
end
```

I'm able to return the user email when testing it in irb.

Not sure if this is the correct way (or the AWS way) to get the user email.... I'd appreciate any comment or feedback...

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Ruby or AWS expert...

But, **verifying the access token you get from Cognito should be as simple
   as verifying the JWT token.**

JWT tokens are self verifying. This means that you dont have to make contact with AWS Cognito service in order to verify that this access token is correct.
At this point your mind is probably being blown... (Mine was)! But JWT (JSON Web Tokens) are a well established spec at this point and there are some super good resources out there for getting your head around how to make use of them.

Here is [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dmvQlBmr34) to some YouTube resources that helped me.

Once you have watched that video watch [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0HLIe3kNvM) for a good example of the encryption/decryption process with public and private keys.

Here is [another link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html) to the official AWS documentation on how to do this.

**TLDR**

You validate the access token using the public key available from the link (given your user pool information)

```
https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json
```

and a standard jwt token library for ruby.

Here is the example given for nodejs in Amazon's documentation:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');
var pem = jwkToPem(jwk);
jwt.verify(token, pem, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decodedToken) {
});
```